# testing sites on current Internet explorer on mint 16

Tags: linux-mint, windows, wine, internet, browser

I need a reliable way to perform compatibility testing for websites on IE 9+.

I'm running Mint 16 and have attempted WINE emulation but it doesn't appear to have a current version.

I would prefer a local solution but have not found one yet.

Is there a way to run IE 9+ on Linux Mint?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for... there are several commercial services that sell access to various web browser versions on a bunch of OS versions for site testing. Or you can run VMs locally. There isn't an IE for Linux.

Comment: @derobert Certainly not an [official](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEs4Linux) one. I've also had luck (not that I endorse it) with [CrossOver Linux](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) (but their docs say IE9+ do not work).

Comment: wow, @derobert, my apologies, you are correct, there wasn't a question in there at all. no more hurried questions for me. I've updated it with a question.

Comment: The sanest approach is probably to run a Windows VM on your machine. Is that an option? Or do you not have a Windows license?

Comment: I don't have a license, but if that is what it comes to...

Comment: @derobert, you don't need a Windows license.  Microsoft provides VMs for this purpose under a special website-testing-only license.

Comment: @cjm I had forgotten entirely about that site. That indeed looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides VMs with various versions of IE at [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) for website testing.  You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to run these on Linux.

Currently, they're offering these Internet Explorer – Windows versions:

- IE6 – XP
- IE8 – XP
- IE7 – Vista
- IE8 – Win7
- IE9 – Win7
- IE10 – Win7
- IE11 – Win7
- IE10 – Win8
- IE11 – Win8.1

Comment: Free VMs! rockon, cjm